# RAML Merge descriptions

Tags: raml

Suppose we have a type `Book` declared as

```
type: object
properties:
  bookId: 
    type: StringId
    description: Book identifier
```

And a type `StringId`

```
type: string
description: UTF-8 string, max length 256 characters
```

Is there any way to merge descriptions from `bookId` in `Book` and `StringId` to get the final description of `bookId` rendered like this

```
Book identifier

UTF-8 string, max length 256 characters
```

I'm using raml2html tool for rendering

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible so far
Let's see if raml2html can be extended for that https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html/issues/425